# How to prove this integral-inequality.

Tags: analysis, inequality, contest-math, integral-inequality

Suppose $f$ is twice differentiable and satisfies $f(0)=0$. Prove the inequality.
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)f'(x)| dx \le\ \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2 dx $$

This is a problem from undergraduate math competition in Korea.

I may use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but it is difficult for me to rearrange this inequality to make form for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

How to prove?

Comment: As written, it's not true, consider e.g. $f(x) = 2x^2$. Is it maybe $\int_0^1 \lvert f(x) f'(x)\rvert\,dx$ on the left hand side?

Comment: Why did two people upvote this question I wonder?

Comment: @SuzuHirose This is an excellent question. Be ready for more if you continue on the site.

Comment: yes  $\int_0^1 |f(x)f'(x)| dx \le\ \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 |f'(x)|^2 dx$

Comment: @Did [Like Michael Knight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otzJszJ9MnA), I am here to prove that one person can make a difference.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Mwahahaa... (Sweet memories from a time when DH was (almost) young.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int f f' dx=\int f df=1/2f^2$$
Thus
$$\int_0^1f(x)f'(x)dx=f(x)|_0^1=1/2f(1)^2$$
since $f(0)=0$.
Let $g(x)=1$ then by Cauchy's theorem
$$\left|\int (f')^2 dx\right|\left|\int g^2 dx\right|\geq\left(\int f'g\,dx\right)^2=(f)^2$$
Thus since $\int_0^1 g(x)dx=1$
$$1/2\int_0^1 (f')^2 dx\geq1/2f(1)^2=\int_0^1 f f' dx$$
The only part I did not get was the absolute value sign around $ff'$, could this be another typo?

Comment: http://blog.naver.com/moleculesum/220182384322 Although it is written in korean, you can recognize the inequality in the problem 5.

Comment: $\int_0^1|\sin'2\pi x|dx=2\pi\int_0^1|\cos2\pi x|dx=8\pi>\int\sin'2\pi x dx=2\pi\int_0^1\cos2\pi x=0$

Comment: To complete this, consider the function $$h(x)=\int_0^x|f'(t)|\,\mathrm dt,$$ and note that $h\geqslant|f|$ and $h'=|f'|$ hence the inequality you proved shows that $$\int(f')^2=\int(h')^2\geqslant2\int hh'\geqslant2\int|f|\,|f'|.$$

Comment: Wow, I got it. thank you :-)